# A program to remove common alphabets from character array

Tags: c

```
void main()
{
    int i, j, k,flag=1;
    char key[10], keyword[10];
    gets(key);
    i=0;
    j=0;
    while(key[i]!='\0') {
        k=0;
        while(keyword[k]!='\0') {
            if(key[i]==keyword[k]) {
                i++;
                flag=0;
                break;
            }
            k++;
        }
        if(flag==1) {
            keyword[j]=key[i];
            j++;
            i++;
        }
        flag=1;
    }
}
```

Here I tried to copy unique alphabets from array to another array ..means duplicate alphabet should not copied in another array..it shows right output but along with that it shows some garbage values like smiley or something till the length of original input array(i.e.key[])

Comment: You need to put a terminator character `'\0'` at the end of your output string.

Comment: Please format your program properly first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a terminator to the unique character string ***both*** at the time it is initialized, and every time a new letter is added:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char redundant[10], unique[10] = { '\0' };

    gets(redundant);

    while (redundant[i] != '\0') {
        int k = 0, flag = 1;

        while (unique[k] != '\0') {
            if (redundant[i] == unique[k]) {
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }
            k++;
        }

        if (flag) {
            unique[j++] = redundant[i];
            unique[j] = '\0';
        }

        i++;
    }

    printf("%s -> %s\n", redundant, unique);

    return(0);
}
```

OUTPUT

```
% ./a.out
warning: this program uses gets(), which is unsafe.
aardvark
aardvark -> ardvk
%
```

Now let's consider a different approach that wastes some space to simplify and speed up the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    unsigned char seen[1 << (sizeof(char) * 8)] = { 0 }; // a flag for every ASCII character
    char redundant[32], unique[32];

    (void) fgets(redundant, sizeof(redundant), stdin); //  gets() is unsafe

    redundant[strlen(redundant) - 1] = '\0'; // toss trailing newline due to fgets()

    int k = 0; // unique character counter

    for (int i = 0; redundant[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (!seen[(size_t) redundant[i]]) {
            unique[k++] = redundant[i];
            seen[(size_t) redundant[i]] = 1; // mark this character as seen
        }
    }

    unique[k] = '\0'; // terminate the new unique string properly

    printf("%s -> %s\n", redundant, unique);

    return 0;
}
```

Instead of a second, inner loop to search if a letter has been copied already, we use an array of flags (boolean), where the letter is the index, to determine if the letter has been processed.

Another thing you might want to think about is whether to treat upper and lower case differently or fold them into one.